# Making navbar sticking to it's previous position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made my navbar to stick to the top only when I scroll down. But again when I scroll up then it instantly gets to the bottom(it's previous position). I want my navbar to stick to the previous position when it's showing in the window. Here is my code-

**HTML:**

```
<section class="section-1">
        <img class="logo" src="./Assets/Asset 2@3x.png" width="320" alt="Brand Icon">
        <p class="description">Luxury Jewelry Store</p>
      
        <nav class="navbar">
          <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Home</a>
          <a href="#" class="navbar-link">My Cart</a>
          <a href="#" class="navbar-link">My Orders</a>
          <a href="#" class="navbar-link">FAQs</a>
          <a href="#" class="navbar-link">About Us</a>
          <div class="search">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass searchIcon"></i>
            <input class="searchBox" placeholder="Search..." type="search">
            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="searchButton">
      
          </div>
        </nav>
      </section>
```

CSS:

```
.section-1{
    height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #92A9BD;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  z-index: 1;
}

.sticky{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
     const navbar = document.querySelector(".navbar");
     if (window.pageYOffset > navbar.offsetTop) {
       navbar.classList.add("sticky");
     } else {
       navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
     }
   };
```

Answer (score 1):

you just need to change the position from fixed to sticky

```
.sticky{position : sticky;
        top:0;
        left:0}
```

no need to mess with right;

Comment: If JS is not a must in your requirement, then can try out `position: sticky; top:0`. But my suggestion is changing in .navbar directly, remove the `bottom:0` and JS could be just remove completely as well. Example on [sticky](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp)

Answer (score 0):

As @harsh-deep and @Zeikman suggested, I removed the JS code and just used sticky as position-

```
.sticky {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
  }
```

and in html file I added sticky to the nav element.
It was really simple! Thank You!